# How to handle Multivalue attribute in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in Data warehouse.

```
Create table customer
(
     id int, 
     name varchar(30),
     address varchar(50)
 );
```

let data in table

```
insert into Customer values(1, 'Smith', 'abc,def, lkj');
insert into Customer values(2, 'James', 'pqr,lmn');
```

i want to split the table address column and insert new row if we have many values. Like

```
1       Smith      abc
1       Smith      def
1       Smith      lkj
2       James      pqr
2       James      lmn
```

i have data of 100000 recrds, please help me in this regards.

Comment: Without context, it is difficult to offer suggestions. Is this related to SSIS at all? Where are these insert statements generated? Why would a customer have multiple addresses that have no finer way of distinguishing among them? Does the table enforce a natural key? Does it have a primary key?

Comment: For identification of data we may use the surrogate key. when new records inserted all the other values will be same, except the address column value with new surrogate key,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_split()` and adjust the `insert` statement:

```
insert into Customer (id, name, address)
    select v.id, v.name, s.value
    from (values (1, 'Smith', 'abc,def,lkj')
         ) v(id, name, address) cross apply
         string_split(v.address, ',') s;
```

You might also want to add a check constraint on `address` so it does not contain a comma.

You would load from a staging table to the final table by doing:

```
insert into Customer (id, name, address)
    select t.id, t.name, s.value
    from staging t cross apply
         string_split(v.address, ',') s;
```

Comment: as i have 100000  records in database table it become very difficult to write query for each record like this... any other solution please.

Comment: @BilalKhan . . . Load the data into a staging table and then transform it for the final table.

Comment: i am facing this problem at staging area,